# I want to add barcode in BI Publisher Report using rtf template ,is it possible?

Tags: obiee, bi-publisher

I have the fonts for the barcode downloaded in the client server but dont know how to use them in the rtf template. I have seen some articles about it on the internet but not able to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want a Code39 barcode. Find a Code39 font that's embeddable (that's very important). If the font file is not embeddable, a user that does not have the font installed will not be able to see the barcode when viewing/printing the PDF.

Install the Code 39 font on your computer so that you can use it in Word when creating your RTF file.

Follow the BI Publisher Administration and Developer guide portions for **Uploading Font Files**, and **Creating Font Mappings** (and Font Mapping Set). You'll want to map it the the font family that's the name of the font you see in Word. Use *Normal* for the style and weight.

Update the BI Publisher configuration to include your font mapping set.

Code 39 barcodes require an asterisk on both sides of the data, so make sure you add those before and after the data you want encoded. Will look like `*DATA_FIELD*` before you change the font. Then set the asterisks and data field you want encoded to the barcode font you want to use.

After completing your RTF file, upload the RTF file template to the server. Process a report using the template. Download the output. You should be able to see the barcode now. Try viewing the file on a machine that doesn't have the font installed to see if it's properly embedded.

The BI Publisher word add-in will not embed the barcode file, so when testing with that, you wont be able to test the barcode.